# How to merge multiple vectors (containing empty vectors) into a new vector？

Tags: arrays, vector, null, dolphindb

Verison: 2.00.8

I took values (vectors) from a window (an arrayVector), and want to merge them into a new vector. I tried function `flatten` to implement my calculation logic, but failed.

```
x = [[1,2,3], [], [4], [5,6]]
flatten(x)
```

Error message:

```
flatten(x) => Couldn't flatten the vector because elements of the vector has inconsistent type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is reported due to the empty vector.

Use function `flatten` after filtering the empty vectors.

```
x = [[1,2,3], [], [4], [5,6]]
flatten(x[flatten(x[,0]!=NULL)])
```

Output:

```
offset  0   1   2   3   4   5
0       1   2   3   4   5   6
```